# WebDav namespace schema

Tags: c#, webdav

can anybody provide any xml schema for DAV: (WebDav) namespace for validation of 
request?

Goal is to check requests before processing request.
I try to search any with ggl, but i can`t find any xsd :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can extract the DTD from the spec, and convert using JING.

2) That being said: don't. You are likely going to create code that fails for perfectly valid requests (consider ordering, and the extensibility rules).

Comment: Just to add to that, real world webdav clients often use properties not in the RFC. For example windows uses its own properties (eg iscollection) which are not part of the Dav RFC but which use the DAV namespace. And some MS clients do not send XML in the request at all.

Comment: brad - note that the latter is perfectly ok

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is like 6 years late but just incase others have this question ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="DAV:" xmlns:dav="DAV:" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="propfind">
    <complexType>
      <choice>
        <sequence>
          <element name="allprop" />
          <element name="include" type="dav:include" minOccurs="0" />
        </sequence>
        <element name="propname" />
        <element name="prop" type="dav:prop" />
      </choice>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <element name="multistatus">
    <complexType>
      <sequence maxOccurs="1">
        <element ref="dav:response" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <element name="responsedescription" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <element name="response">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="href" type="anyURI" />
        <choice>
          <sequence>
            <element name="href" type="anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="status" type="string" />
          </sequence>
          <element name="propstat" type="dav:propstat" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </choice>
        <element ref="dav:error" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="responsedescription" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <element name="propertyupdate">
    <complexType>
      <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="remove" type="dav:prop-remove" />
        <element name="set" type="dav:prop-set" />
      </choice>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <element name="lockinfo">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="lockscope" type="dav:lockscope" />
        <element name="locktype" type="dav:locktype" />
        <element name="owner" minOccurs="0" type="dav:owner" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <element name="prop" type="dav:prop" />

  <element name="supportedlock">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="lockentry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="lockscope" type="dav:lockscope" />
              <element name="locktype" type="dav:locktype" />
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <complexType name="owner" mixed="true">
    <sequence>
      <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
    <anyAttribute />
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="lockscope">
    <choice>
      <element name="shared" />
      <element name="exclusive" />
    </choice>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="locktype">
    <choice>
      <element name="write" />
    </choice>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="prop-remove">
    <sequence>
      <element name="prop" type="dav:prop" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="prop-set">
    <sequence>
      <element name="prop" type="dav:prop" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="prop">
    <sequence>
      <any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="activelock">
    <sequence>
      <element name="lockscope" type="dav:lockscope" />
      <element name="locktype" type="dav:locktype" />
      <element name="depth">
        <simpleType>
          <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="0" />
            <enumeration value="1" />
            <enumeration value="infinity" />
          </restriction>
        </simpleType>
      </element>
      <element name="owner" type="dav:owner" minOccurs="0" />
      <element name="timeout" type="dav:timeout" />
      <element name="locktoken" type="dav:locktoken" minOccurs="0" />
      <element name="lockroot" type="dav:lockroot" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <simpleType name="timeout">
    <restriction base="string">
      <pattern value="(Infinite)|(Second-\d+)" />
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <complexType name="lockentry">
    <sequence>
      <element name="lockscope" type="dav:lockscope" />
      <element name="locktype" type="dav:locktype" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="lockroot">
    <sequence>
      <element name="href" type="anyURI" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="locktoken">
    <sequence>
      <element name="href" type="anyURI" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="include">
    <sequence>
      <any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <element name="error">
    <complexType>
      <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="lock-token-matches-request-uri" />
        <element name="lock-token-submitted">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="href" type="anyURI" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="no-conflicting-lock">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="href" type="anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="no-external-entities" />
        <element name="preserved-live-properties" />
        <element name="propfind-finite-depth" />
        <element name="cannot-modify-protected-property" />
        <any namespace="##other" />
      </choice>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <complexType name="propstat">
    <sequence>
      <element name="prop" type="dav:prop" />
      <element name="status" type="string" />
      <element ref="dav:error" minOccurs="0" />
      <element name="responsedescription" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
      <element name="location" type="dav:location" minOccurs="0" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="location">
    <sequence>
      <element name="href" type="anyURI" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```